# Comparing a SimpleStringProperty in a search

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TableView that is populated on a scene. I am searching the objects properties to see if they match, and the property is returning StringProperty [value: 3]. I am just trying to see the proper way to complete this comparison.

Here is the code:

```
@FXML
public void searchParts(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
  System.out.println("Searching for part: " + searchPart.getText());
  String partSearchable = searchPart.getText();
      for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
         System.out.println(parts.get(i).nameProperty());           

          if (parts.get(i).nameProperty().equals(new SimpleStringProperty(partSearchable))) {
            partsList.clear();
            partsList.add(parts.get(i));
            populateTable();
            break;
         }  
     }
    partsList.clear();
    populateTable();
}
```

Here is the getter method in the part class:

```
public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty(){
    return new SimpleStringProperty(name.get());
}
```

What would the proper way to do this comparison?

Comment: You shouldn't have to create new SimpleStringProperty objects just to compare the name properties.

Comment: The actual logic of your `searchParts` method makes no sense at all. Do you intend to search only for one matching item? And why do you clear the list after doing the search... you will always end up with an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not create a new property in the property accessor method. You should also expose the type as `StringProperty`, not `SimpleStringProperty`.

Do:

```
public StringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name ;
}
```

When you want to perform comparisons, compare the contents of the property to the string of interest:

```
if (parts.get(i).nameProperty().get().equals(partSearchable)) { ... }
```

If you also define the usual `get` methods in your class:

```
public final String getName() {
    return nameProperty().get();
}

// and, though it's irrelevant to this question, usually also 
public final void setName(String name) {
    nameProperty().set(name);
}
```

then of course you can just do

```
if (parts.get(i).getName().equals(partSearchable)) { ... }
```

Comment: I made these changes but the comparison is still not working. When I print out parts.get(i).getName(); it prints out the property like this... still : StringProperty [value: 3] .

Comment: @Jamie How are you setting the value of `name` in the first place? Maybe the problem is there. Don't take this the wrong way, but there is so much that is wrong with the code you have posted, you probably need to back up and understand some basic Java before you try to use a moderately complex framework like JavaFX.

Comment: This is how I have to learn it for school unfortunately, I have learned a lot so far. I am going to make a change in a little bit( I just noticed that my logic would make the table never populate, gonna try to separate into two Observable lists. )

Comment: @Jamie If `nameProperty()` and `getName()` are giving the same results, you haven't done it the way I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if (parts.get(i).getName().equals(partSearchable)) {
```